# How to map html file to Filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE and want to map html file to Filter. I do the following in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>VerifierFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/test.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, if I access `http://localhost/test.html`, it seems that filter code is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR GAE doesn't serve static files through the same servlet infrastructure. So that's why your filter isn't applied.

You could try renaming your test.html to test.jsp. That will serve the static file as a jsp and the filter should be applied. However it won't get faster that way, but if performance is not a concern for you, than it might be a viable option.